# For daypilot calendar control, how to display mon to fri instead of date on the column name

Tags: c#, sql, webforms, timetable, daypilot

[image]

[image]

currently mine only displays the date on the column name. I would want to display mon to fri which correpond to the correct date of course. Etc I want to display mon instead of 17/03/2014, I want to display tue instead of 18/03/2014 and so on. bumpss up

**MY SOURCE**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="number2.aspx.cs" Inherits="number2" %>

<%@ Register assembly="DayPilot" namespace="DayPilot.Web.Ui" tagprefix="DayPilot" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: center">

        <asp:Label ID="lblVenue" runat="server" 
            style="font-size: xx-large; font-weight: 700" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        <daypilot:daypilotcalendar 
     id="DayPilotCalendar1" 
     runat="server" 
     DataStartField="eventstart" 
     DataEndField="eventend"
     DataTextField="name" 
     DataValueField="id" 
     Days="5" 
     OnEventMove="DayPilotCalendar1_EventMove" 
     EventMoveHandling="CallBack" BackColor="#0066FF" BusinessBeginsHour="8" 
            BusinessEndsHour="19" CssOnly="False" EventBackColor="#66FF99" 
            HourBorderColor="Lime" HourHalfBorderColor="#0066FF" 
            HourNameBackColor="#6699FF" HourNameBorderColor="#0066FF" HoverColor="#0066FF" 
            NonBusinessBackColor="#0066FF" style="top: 0px; left: 0px"
     >
    </daypilot:daypilotcalendar>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MY CODE BEHIND**

```
public partial class number2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblVenue.Text = Session["roomvalue"] != null ? Session["roomvalue"].ToString() : "";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2014, 03, 17));
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days);
            DataBind();
        }
    }


        private DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [id], [name], [name2], [eventstart], [eventend] FROM [event] WHERE NOT (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

@Xenolightning  dun hav the event that u mention

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at their [Online Documentation](http://doc.daypilot.org/calendar/), there is an extension event `BeforeHeaderRender` that you can subscribe to. Here you can change the column header label. See their example [here](http://doc.daypilot.org/calendar/column-header-customization/)

```
protected void DayPilotCalendar1_BeforeHeaderRender(object sender, BeforeHeaderRenderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Html += e.Date.ToString('dddd');
}
```

EDIT:

Actual solution:

Setting the property `DayPilotCalendar.HeaderDateFormat` to `dddd` changes it to "monday, Tuesday..."

Comment: I added a image. Don't have the beforeheaderrender u mention

Comment: @Jordjmax Are you using the Full or Lite version?

Comment: I didn't pay for it. it's lite, i download it from here. http://www.daypilot.org/download.html. @Xenolightning

Comment: Try following [this](http://www.daypilot.org/choosing_headerdateformat_datetime_tostring_parameters.html). Outside of that, without installing it, I won't be able to help you any further. Try searching their documentation, there may have something I missed.

Comment: DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2014, 03, 17)).ToString("dddd");  I tried this got error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'  How do i write it correct?  @Xenolightning

Comment: @Jordjmax Your `StartDate` property was correctly set. Look for another property `DayFormat` and set that the value of that to `dddd`. Check out their [demo](http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Lite/Calendar/HeaderDateFormat.aspx), it's definitely possible.

Comment: i msg u in chatroom. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49916/discussion-between-jordjmax-and-xenolightning @Xenolightning

Answer (score 1):

In the calendar control, set

```
HeaderDateFormat="dddd"
```

This will then show day names only